# Replace Price Difference with Actual Price in Magento Configurable Product Options 1.9

Tags: magento

Configure Product :

Base Price :Rs.1000

Size : Small - 1500
Size : Medium - 2000

instead of increment with base price, want to replace this to main price

checked few solution but nothing is working with Magento version 1.9

Thankyou

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225093/replace-price-difference-with-actual-price-in-magento-configurable-product-optio?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is performed by javascript. You need to modify the method getOptionLabel in js/varien/configurable.js

The first few lines of the method look like this:

```
getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
    var price = parseFloat(price);
```

You need to change it to:

```
getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
    var basePrice = parseFloat(this.config.basePrice);
    // 'price' as passed is the RELATIVE DIFFERENCE. We won't use it.
    //  The ABSOLUTE DIFFERENCE is in option.price (and option.oldPrice)
    var absoluteDifference = parseFloat(option.price);
    var absoluteFinalPrice = basePrice + absoluteDifference;
    // var price = parseFloat(price);
    var price = absoluteFinalPrice;
```

To remove + and - symbols in the options, find call to this.formatPrice function and change the second paramter to false in each call.

Just like this:

```
if(price){
        if (this.taxConfig.showBothPrices) {
            str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(excl, false) + ' (' + this.formatPrice(price, false) + ' ' + this.taxConfig.inclTaxTitle + ')';
        } else {
            str+= ' ' + this.formatPrice(price, false);
        }
```

Remember, if you make changes in core magento files, then next time you upgrade Magento you will probably lose your changes. Better to create another file like js/varien/custom_configurable.js or whatever name you like, and call it in the config file (product.xml) for whatever theme you are using.

That's all.

Note: This method is not tested on Magento version >1.7

Comment: are you changing correct file and also have you refreshed magento cache?